# Différence entre "quelque chose d'autre" et "autre chose"

Tags: locutions

> Je voudrais autre chose.
>
> Je voudrais quelque chose d'autre.

Toutes deux se traduisent par

> I would like something else.

Mais y a-t-il des différences entre *autre chose* et *quelque chose d'autre* (e.g. registre) ?

Comment: Note a big difference in actual usage, though, where one is significantly preferred to the other. e.g.: "À défaut d’autre chose" is almost exclusively said instead of "À défaut de quelque chose d'autre". Likewise: "Comme s'il pouvait s'agir d'autre chose" instead of "Comme s'il pouvait s'agir de quelque chose d'autre". And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Autre chose » et « Quelque chose d'autre » signifient tous deux soit « une chose différente de toutes celles dont il vient d'être question » soit « quelque chose en plus (et donc différent de ce dont il a été question) » ([Wiktionaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autre_chose))
. Il n'y a pas de différence de registre.

Answer (score 1):

La deuxième expression est nuancée d'une certaine incertitude.